# How do I automatically clean up my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp directory?

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss7.x, vfs, tmp

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final on my dev machine, a Mac 10.9.1.  I’m trying to get my /tmp/vfs directory to clean itself up (with a max caching time of a day), so I added this line to my $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf file …

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.vfs.cache=org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache -Djboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime=86400"
```

I confirmed that the system properties are getting loaded when I start my server.  However, after restart, I still see directories in the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs that are more than a day old.  Is something about the above wrong or is there another parameter I need to add to get that directory to clean out?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to set VFS system properties.
Also your properties come from VFS2 that was used AS5/6 times.

AS7+ has newer/different implementation of VFS and handles this things differently.

There ware few bugs in 7.1.x in this area and ware fixed in WildFly 8 Beta1.

See [jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1547) for more info about this.

I would recommend you upgrading to WildFly 8.

Comment: I'm not able to upgrade from JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  When you say "AS7+ has newer/different implementation of VFS and handles this things differently", can you be specific about how I would clean up the vfs directory?